# Can I get old photos use Google streetview API?

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

Recently, Google map could go back in time Street View by "TimeMachine".
I couldn't find the way in the APIs.
Is their TimeMachine parameter for change the time?
Have I any other way if we don't have API to get the data of "TimeMachine"?
For example, enter a URL of Street View directly.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is not possible using the API.

This feature request from the official Google Maps API bug tracker covers exactly this funcitonality:

[Issue 6718:    Feature Request: Access to Street View images from different times](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6718)

It it open since May 2014.

Comment: Thanks!
For all you gave me fast answer, Sorry for my late reply.
I'm hoping that it will be implemented quickly...